# Centred pop-up with styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I'm creating a website to learn how to write HTML / CSS & JSS and I'm having a little issue with loading a popup box such as this which will run at the click of a button  https://gyazo.com/57865b1e9df5054be787f231693a6a6f

I've found this solution, but when I've tried to implement it on the c9.io website I'm getting an error:

**Width is not defined please fix or add /*global width*/**

```
function PopupCenterDual(url, title, w, h) {
   // Fixes dual-screen position Most browsers Firefox
var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;

width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;

var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;
var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;
var newWindow = window.open(url, title, 'scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);

// Puts focus on the newWindow
if (window.focus) {
newWindow.focus();
}
```

When running the script, it opens the window in the top left. I believe it might be that I haven't set the width of the box I want to open, but cannot find the correct place to do so.

Any help & explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From where are you calling `PopupCenterDual` method?

Comment: From a homepage, this is located in a javascript file

Comment: This is the method definition, I am asking about the method calling. Which will be either a button / link `onclick` event.

Comment: <a href="javascript:PopupCenterDual('add-item.html');" >example</a>

Comment: You are missing other parameters. Call like, `<a href="javascript:PopupCenterDual('add-item.html', 'Add Item', 500, 300);" >`

Comment: What does the 'Add Item' param refer to? @ParkashKumar the 500, 300 is height and width?

Comment: `Add Item` will be the title of the window, showing on the top bar.

Comment: Also, add `var` before `width` and `height` in `PopupCenterDual` function. Or declare them outside the method as `var width = 0, height = 0;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, the [example provided](https://gyazo.com/57865b1e9df5054be787f231693a6a6f) is a div.

If you would use a div instead an external window, you could use pure CSS:

```
.popup {
   /*center the div*/
   position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

   /*dimensions and other settings*/
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width: 50%;
   padding: 2em;
   }

body {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Thanks to [Chris Choyier](https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/)

Answer (score -1):

This is a centered div styling, i took it from a function i use for displaying messages in a div: `style="position: fixed;width: 50%; left: 25%; top: 30%;"`